# How to apply custom layout in Google Slides API when I create a presentation

Tags: python, google-slides-api

I try to create a presentation to use it as a template. And I need to define objectIDs of layouts (so I can easily create slide and apply layout). The only way I can define it, is to create a new presentation which have custom layouts and master.

The point that when I add master and layout keys into request, google slides api ignore it. It apply simple-light theme to the presentation.

How can I fix it?

Here is example of the code (I tried to add elements to slide and layout, but result is the same)

```
body = {
    "masters": [
        {
            "pageType": "MASTER", 
            "objectId": "Master", 
            "masterProperties": {
                "displayName": "Master Name"
            }
        }
    ], 

    "layouts": [
        {
            "pageType": "LAYOUT", 
            "objectId": "Layout", 
            "layoutProperties": {
                "displayName": "Layout Name", 
                "name": "Layout Name", 
                "masterObjectId": "Master"
            }
        }
    ],

    "slides": [
        {
            "slideProperties": {
                "masterObjectId": "Master", 
                "layoutObjectId": "Layout"
            },
            "objectId": "Slide"
        }
    ],

    "title": "2019-11-12 - Template", 
    "locale": "en-US"
}


presentation   = service.presentations().create(body = body).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create), the method `presentations.create` only creates a blank presentation. Only `title` and, if you provide it, `presentationId` will be taken into account. "Other fields in the request, including any provided content, are ignored". It is basically the same behaviour you get [with Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create).

So in order to add content, styles, properties, etc. to the presentation, you have to use [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate).

I hope this is of any help to you.